# How to use JQuery selector for select input name and input name in array?

Tags: jquery

can you help me. I need select with JQuery input with name and input with name in array.

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="shippingAddress[name]">
```

I try this, but this not work.

```
var name = $('[name^="name"]');
```

Comment: Is `shippingAddress[name]` supposed to be the value of the `name` attribute or its own attribute?

Comment: `shippingAddress[name]` what is this?

Comment: Sorry, Now it is good., bat I need find, by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
var name = $('[name*="name"]');
```

That will select any element where its `name` attributes value contains the substring "name", so will match both `<input type="text" name="name"/>` and `<input type="text" name="shippingAddress[name]"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

try attribute selector

```
var name = $('[name^="shippingAddress\\[name\\]]');
```

Answer (score 0):

To select input with name:

```
$('input[name=name]')
```

To select input with name as array field:

```
$('input[name="' + shippingAddress + '[]"]')
```